Data is not synchronizing between Firebase and Google Ads for iOS apps
Firebase conversions on Google Ads?
I haven't been able to solve this problem for over a month now. Conversions from Firebase and GA4 are not being transmitted to Google Ads. The issue is only with iOS apps. I've attached several screenshots showing that conversions are correctly logged in Firebase and GA4, but they do not appear in Google Ads.

The app is developed in Flutter.
I have added the App Store ID and Team ID in Firebase.

Can anyone help, even with advice? I've read all the forums and couldn't find a solution to the problem.
screenshots Firebasefirebase
screenshots GA4
screenshots ADS
